# Use jquery's each() to loop through php array on success return

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, for-loop

How do I loop using JQuery's `each()` to get the data `[sku]` and `[imagePath]` that is returned to my success function from PHP array using AJAX's post?

Below is the array.

```
Array
(
[id] => 195
[sku] => Lemonpunnet
[variantName] => Lemon punnet
[qty] => 500
[productId] => SGG-PRD-3
[prodVariantStatus] => 1
[visible] => 1
[pricing] => Array
    (
        [price] => 660
    )

[modifiedDate] => 1448294444
[createDate] => 1448294444
[productVariantImages] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 268
                [imageName] => lemon.png
                [imagePath] => http://web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/lemon.png
                [visible] => 1
                [featured] => 
                [modifiedDate] => 1448294444
                [createDate] => 1448294444
            )

    )
)
```

)

And the following is what I currently have but it is not returning any data.

```
 $('#selectVariant').change(function () {
    var sku = $('#selectVariant :selected').val();
    var sessionId="<?php echo $sessionId; ?>";
    var dataString='sku='+ sku +'&sessionId='+sessionId;
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>ajax-helper/search_variant.php",
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.variants,function(key,value){
                alert(key+":"+value);
            });
        }
    });
        return false;
```

Comment: `data.variants`??? So what do you get for `console.log(data)`?!

Comment: @A.Wolff if i alert(data) in my success, i am able to get the array

Comment: I don't see any `variants` property. Is array you posted the returned data or data.variants sample?

Comment: @A.Wolff oh crap, it's from data....... now i removed it and it's returning the data, how do i specify if i need to get just one item etc 'imagePath'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `.each` on the `data` response.
Or if you want an individual element of the `data` object, address it directly.

Example:

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        console.log(key+":"+value);
    });

    // outside of the each
    console.log(data.sku);
    $.each(data.productVariantImages, function(){
        console.log(this.imagePath);
    })

}
```

Comment: `data.imagePath` is undefined here, it is property of nested array `productVariantImages`

Comment: `productVariantImages` is a js array, you need to iterate through it to get all relevant `imagePath` properties :) If there is only one, it would be: `data.productVariantImages[0].imagePath`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is JSON string:

```
alert(data['sku']);

$.each(data['productVariantImages'],function(key,value){
   $.each(value,function(key2,value2){
      if (key2 == 'imagePath') {
         alert(value2);
      }
   });
});
```